# neo4j full text search get property that contain keyword

Tags: neo4j

Referring to the documentation https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/schema/index/#schema-index-fulltext-search-query

Consider below full text search query

CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("titlesAndDescriptions", 'Full Metal Jacket') YIELD node, score
RETURN node

How do I get which property matches the search keyword keyword. (i.e in above example 'Full Metal Jacket' found in title or description ?)

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
WITH 'Full Metal Jacket' AS searchString 

CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("titlesAndDescriptions", searchString) YIELD node, score 
WITH node,
     node.title CONTAINS searchString AS inTitle,
     node.description CONTAINS searchString AS inDescription

RETURN node,inTitle,inDescription
```

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion. This partially solve my problem. However if searchString contains wildcards then this won't work.